# Debian private ppa or alternative

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to create a private ppa, but **every** answer ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194574/how-do-i-create-a-private-ppa-server), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194574/how-do-i-create-a-private-ppa-server/267649#267649)) to "how do I create a private ppa?" has started with "Well, it's not going to be easy", something similar to that or just something that confused me.

Assuming that I know nothing about ppa's, apache-setup, servers, can someone either **a**) explain explicitly and clearly how this is done, **b**) explain an alternative (other than git) or **c**) at least point me in the right direction with a lot of verbosity so that I can begin to understand all of this? That is can someone provide me with a way of distributing a Debian package (preferably with a private ppa) and explain it very simply?

The solution now is to use git (it's 10 times easier than making a private ppa hosted on a private server), and git might be the right way to go, but I think for the future we still want to create a package, and we should probably know how to do this.

Comment: Also, I've been getting downvoted a lot, so if you do downvote please explain why. Also, try to be reasonable. I'm pretty young and inexperienced. I also don't particularly care how many "points" I have on stack overflow, so I don't mind if you downvote, but what really annoys me is when people don't answer a question, don't say anything but still downvote for whatever reason. I need some feed back! It's the only way for me to catch up in the information age!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may start at

- https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/bittner-195120/howto-build-your-own-debian-repository-2863/

Or ask for help on an IRC channel:

- https://wiki.debian.org/IRC#Debian_IRC_channels

To restrict access on a debian repository, a simple [Basic authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) can be used if you are using HTTP protocol. If you are using FTP, you can use the login and the password of the user. If you are using SSH, you can use a public/private key access.
Check it out: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/513/Restrict_Access_To_Your_Private_Debian_Repository

Comment: I have, unfortunately, read that page thoroughly. I will continue to examine debian.org's docs, but they are still relatively confusing for a novice. I believe I would use reprepro, but I don't know how to configure Apache to keep it private. I don't have apache installed or setup, and I don't know how to. :(

Comment: Yes; lot's of hashtags. It *must* be a useful site. :) Thanks. I will have to try it out.

Comment: Seems that you only need to create your .deb files, generate a folder structure with `apt-ftparchive` and push everything on a ftp/http host just like publishing html files on a static website

Comment: But does that keep it private? I want absolutely nothing to be accessible w/o a password or key

Comment: Alright!! I have been diving into debian packaging and many other things head first. I'm afraid I am running out of steam, but here I go, anyway! I've been telling myself "I think I can" for the past month and a half, so I just have one small hill to get up. Thanks for your help.